# Soup object to text file

Tags: python

I referred to a solution on stack over flow regarding this problem but somehow it still isn't working. It shows this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3604: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code for the program is:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
fhand = urllib.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Francis_Egan')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand.read())
fhand.close()
f = open("myoutputfile.txt","a")
f.write(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follows:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
fhand = urllib.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Francis_Egan')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand).get_text()
f = open("myoutputfile.txt","w")
f.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```